# git ignore all filetypes expect special type in subfolders also

Tags: git

I have a root folder which has size in `GBs`. Lot of it is `build` stuff.
I want to only source control folder `code` under root and also only `*.c` `*.h` files in it. There are other project and solution files like `*.sln` in `code`.

My `.gitignore` file is :

```
*
!/code
!.gitignore
!/code/**/*.h
!/code/**/*.c
```

`git add .` and `git status` shows

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   code/a.c
        new file:   code/a.h
```

Although, this works for folder `code` but it does not work for any subfolder of `code`. I also have `*.h` and `*.c` files inside `code/f1` and `code/f2` and so on.

My `git --version` is `git version 1.9.5-preview20150319`. I am on windows.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: You should **re-think** the way you organize your code. Adding *all* to `.gitignore` and then the exceptions (including `.gitignore` itself) looks to me like something that could be avoided if you placed all your build stuff into a single folder ("./build"?) and you added it to the `.gitignore`, along with the file types you want to ignore (`*.exe`,`*~`,etc)

Comment: @KeillЯandor My code has `build` and other `code` and `code2` folders.. which is good. I just did not mentioned to reduce the complexity of question. The real question is that if i can not selectively remove `.sln`, `.txt` what not.. files in `code`. so how should i write my `.gitignore` file. and there are many such files in `code`.. Git can take time in certain operations then in big repo.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. You **can** selectively remove certain files across the project. For example, for ignoring ".o" files, simply add `*.o` to `.gitignore`

Comment: @KeillЯandor i do not know about what all kind of files i want to remove.. i know what i want to source control.. `*.c` `*.h`

Answer (score 1):

Simply write

```
!code/**.c
!code/**.h
```

Don't use absolute paths (starting with '/') when using **.

Comment: if i do that, would not git look into all other directories also for these files? That can take time.

Comment: Answer updated. Use 'code' folder name but don't start it with a slash '/'

Comment: are you suggesting only to put this in my `.gitignore` file.. ? I tried to replace corresponding lines in `.giignore` file. that did not worked.. in `git status` code folder never shows as untracked file..

Comment: no that does not work either.. can not get folders second level deep.